# creative alternatives to "web"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What are some good terms for a collection of lines. My actual use-case involves networked collections of lines of thought, but I'm interested in hearing mathematical/scientific terms.

Differently put, as the title states, I'm looking for creative alternatives to the term ***web.***

Comment: Well, _net_ has the same sense as _web_ in most cases, and, specifically for metaphoric lines, _bundle_ is a common term. It depends on whether and how and in what pattern they're connected (whatever "connection" might map to in your thought metaphor); bundles of lines need not intersect, but they do have some relation to one another, perhaps being results of coordinate equations, or the same algorithm with different inputs.

Comment: If the elements within the "web" are interconnected in some way, perhaps they could be described as a ***mesh***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A set (related terms:  union, intersection, complement, difference, symmetric difference), a power set, a truth table, a Venn diagram
- A collection
- An aggregation
- Classifications
- A "string theory" of ideas
- A think map (see http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/set?&o=100074&s=t)
- An organizational chart
- Class
- Protocol
- An outline
- An index
- An abstract
- A glossary
- A Concatenation (more disorganized than organized)
- Potpourri (disorganized)
- Melange (disorganized)

I'm sorry if my list (oops, there's another word--list) is kind of "stream of consciousness," but *set* (and its related terms) is probably your best bet, at least from the perspective of mathematics. As for science, well, that's not my thing, though I suppose one could use the terms kingdom, genus, species, and the like in creative ways in organizing lines of thought!